# mark some places on Israel map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web-scraping

I'm trying to use a small portion of js to web-scrape israeli address from some websites and eventually mark those addresses on Israel map.

I have two problems and maybe someone could help me out

1. I managed to fetch the web-pages content, but was not able to find the address string in them. The reason is that there is no fixed pattern. The web sites are different. I can try find the element that contains hebrew before the telephone number. But what is the right syntax for that ?

#1

```
<p type="" title="" multilinks-noscroll="true">
<a target="_new" href="http://maps.google.com/?hl=iw&ie=UTF8&ll=32.226743,34.747009&spn=2.183969,2.69989&z=9" multilinks-noscroll="true">בן גוריון 61, בת ים</a>
</p>
<p>03-5066338</p>
```

#2

```
<div style="padding-top: 5px;">
<div>כתובת: יהודה הלוי 12 ת"א (נוה צדק)</div>
</div>
<div style="padding-top: 5px;"> </div>
<div style="padding-top: 5px;">
<div>טלפון: 1-700-707-607</div>
</div>
```

2. I read the Israel's streets names are not locatable via google map API. Is there any other recommended service API to locate the addresses I fetch from phase 1 on a map ?

Thanks in advance to any help

Comment: For example #1 above, you could search for attributes with href~=maps.google.com, and pick out the address from the link text.

Comment: How would you select with js\jQuery the first element that contains hebrew and is right before a telephone regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the yahoo API for geocoding http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/

It was originally implemented to find variable street addresses in web pages and *may* solve the problem you have

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it could solve my problem in recognizing the address in each web-page where the srtacture is different from one to another ?

Comment: That was the original design -- i.e. extracting variable address formats from web pages (I was the designer) but not sure what the product does these days, so try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: At any rate, can I put multiple flags on one map ?

Comment: I see lot of google maps applications using multiple flags on the map - however it would not know of hand  the specifics in the API as how that is done. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the [Waze geocoding API](http://www.waze.co.il/dev/documentation/) for Israel or [OpenStreetMap's](http://www.openstreetmap.org) data; they seem to have some comprehensive info for Tel Aviv at least.